# Restangular service getList('pit') sending parameters

Tags: javascript, angularjs, restangular

I have a restangular service that I create like so:

```js
(function() {
    'use strict';

    angular
        .module("myapp")
        .factory('stats.api.service', StatsApi);

    StatsApi.$inject = ['Restangular'];

    function StatsApi(Restangular) {
        return Restangular.service('stats');
    }
}());
```

I add inject this factory into a service as `api` and try to make calls off of it. Most of them work, but a certain one doesn't.

For instance, this calls works. (where `id` is a string with the id I want.

```js
api.getList().then(function(data) {
    console.log(data);
});
```

The above call uses the following url: http://localhost/myapp/api/stats

That is the URL I expect.

Now, if I use this code:

```js
api.getList('pit').then(function(data) {
    console.log(data);
});
```

It calls http://localhost/myapp/api/stats?0=p&1=i&2=t

Now I may be just missing something, but it should call http://localhost/myapp/api/stats/pit, right?

Any ideas as to what I am doing wrong and how I can fix it?

EDIT:

I figured out how to call the URL I want, but I still feel like it doesn't follow what the documentation says. To call http://localhost/myapp/api/stats/pit I have to use

```js
api.one('pit').getList().then(function(data) {
    console.log(data);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the method descriptions at [github repo of restangular](https://github.com/mgonto/restangular#collection-methods) you will see **getList of collection** takes `queryParams as first paramter`.

> getList([queryParams, headers]): Gets itself again (Remember this is a
>   collection)

on the other hand **getlist of element** takes `subElement as first parameter`.

> getList(subElement, [queryParams, headers]): Gets a nested resource. 
>   subElement is mandatory.  It's a string with the name of the nested
>   resource (and URL).  For example buildings

personally I wanted use `service` feature of Restangular but in many cases it force me to do extra works on many thing. My suggestion, to build url use `one()` or `all()`.